# Cannot set cookies dynamically in api request on a site with laravel and angular

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Hello everyone I have an app where I need to make an API request and that app is made of laravel and angular. Laravel for the backend and angular is for the front end. The API is for subscribing a user to a specific task. On my app, I need to make an API request which needs cookies that are being generated from the backend ( most probably I'm not sure ). So those cookies enable my API to work properly. I have all the things ready but **`I can't set the cookies dynamically`**. The problem is I'm not sure where are those cookies are being generated from. I have created a custom function that calls the API with some specific parameter and then it just subscribes the user with that privilege that the user was subscribed to. 
My app workflow is like below

- on the angular, I submit the payment form
- after the form submission my app goes to the payment sandbox provided by the third party ( this is a completely different server )
- then after a successful payment transaction it redirects to my laravel app and calls the custom function that I made and tries to subscribe the user with the features user paid for.

on the last step, I can't get the cookie that was needed to make the user subscribe to the plan that they paid for. This time I need to get the cookie from the API which I can get by making the request manually. as it's a payment procedure I can not make it manual and the whole process needs to go automatically.

My API is okay no problem with that **`The problem is that I can not make the cookies dynamically and also I am not being able to use those dynamically generated cookies each time a request is made`**.

- following is the main api function

```
/**
         * Create a new subscription.
         *
         * @return JsonResponse
         */
        public function store()
        {
            $this->authorize('update', Subscription::class);

            $this->validate($this->request, [
                'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id|unique:subscriptions',
                'renews_at' => 'required_without:ends_at|date|nullable',
                'ends_at' => 'required_without:renews_at|date|nullable',
                'plan_id' => 'required|integer|exists:billing_plans,id',
                'description' => 'string|nullable',
            ]);

            $subscription = $this->subscription->create($this->request->all());

            return $this->success(['subscription' => $subscription]);
            console.log('running');
        }
```

- following is my custom function

```
    public function apicall(Request $request){
            $curl = curl_init();
            $xsrf_token = request()->Cookie("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            $cookie = request()->Cookie("Cookie");

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'localhost:4200/secure/billing/subscriptions',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                      "user_id": 3,
                      "renews_at": "2021-01-29 18:00:00",
                      "plan_id": 1,
                      "description": "null"
              }',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                  $xsrf_token,
                  $cookie,
                  'Host: localhost:4200',
                  'Referer: http://localhost:4200/admin/subscriptions?page=1&per_page=15',
                  'Origin: http://localhost:4200',
                  'Content-Type: application/json'
                ),
              ));
              
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return redirect('http://localhost:4200/dashboard')->with('status', 'Success');    
        }
```

- On web.php I have configured routes and everything else. My API and payment redirection all are working well but The users are not being subscribed or I can say may API is not being able to verify the request's owner or the request's validation so it's not being able to give me any **200** response. It just gives me **302** with the `found` tag. So how should I set the cookie dynamically so that the request cookie can be matched by the system's subscription cookie?

  Can anyone help me with this? I need to solve this as soon as possible.

Comment: what is `console.log('running');` doing in laravel?

Comment: sorry to say but that was on my laravel app and I really didn't notice that. The application was pre-built and I was assigned to add the payment gateway. As I completed the payment method and now I need to add the subscription to the users I was facing the issue and posted it here. 
Really I didn't notice that.

Comment: when you are redirecting then redirect your response with cookies,`withCookie(cookie('key', 'value', 20000));`

Comment: refer this question [how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5), [attaching-cookies-to-responses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses)

Comment: @bhucho thank you for the comment. 
So the initial step should be that I must create a cookie on my app and later I should get that cookie from my request script? right?

Comment: send cookie with response whenever you want to set it then use it simple no need of curl or anything

Comment: Thank you 
i'll try it this way then .